# Specify name of column with a variable and pull it using row() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working with CodeIgniter to pull content from a column. The columns I can selecte from are named as "referred_user_1","referred_user_2","referred_user_3","referred_user_4","referred_user_5". Depending on the user's input, which is an integer ranging from 1-5, I'd like to specify the column. For example, if the user input "2", then I would like to pull data from column "referred_user_2"; if the user input "5", then column "referred_user_5".

Code:

```
    $id=89343;
    $referred_user_number=substr($this->encrypt->decode($code),-1); //depending on the user's input, $referred_user_number could be from number 1 to 5

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query_email=$this->db->get('email_signup_refer_send')->row();
    $referred_user = $query_email->'referred_user_.$referred_user_number'; //this is where I run into problem and error msg is shown as below
```

PHP error msg is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''referred_user_.$referred_user' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Advice is appreciated!

Comment: Did not work. Error msg: Undefined property: stdClass::$referred_user_.$referred_user_number

Comment: remember quotations and curly brackets `$query_email->{"referred_user_$referred_user_number"}` check var_dump() to see the properties

Comment: Here's the code: $referred_user = $query_email->{'referred_user_$referred_user_number'}; var_dump($referred_user); the result is "null"

Comment: you're still using single quotes based on your comment use double quotes

Comment: Apologies I didn't know it was gonna make a difference with the double quote! It works now. What's the reason for using double quotes?

Comment: if you use `'` single quotes they will be not recognized as variables but as literal strings, so you need to use `"` double quotes so it will be interpreted as a variable